# [Turtlebot] Autonomous map building

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, exploration, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm looking to have my turtlebot autonomously build a map of an area, without needing to be manually teleoperated or working on an existing map.

I have used frontier_exploration package (wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration). But it looks like my turtlebot isn't working well with frontier_exploration's default settings. And I haven't seen any good examples of how to config frontier_exploration package with turtlebot. So it would be great to see some examples about turtlebot builds map using frontier_exploration package, or some alternative packages to solve my problem.

Thanks,
DuongBH

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187512/%5Bturtlebot%5D-autonomous-map-building/) by [hades](https://answers.ros.org/users/19822/hades/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The sample configuration is relatively robot-agnostic, however there are several different usecases outlined on the wiki. Also, the sensor setup should mirror your navigation stack configuration, so that would the first place I'd look for issues.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0